# Nativescript http post response is undefined

Tags: angular, http, undefined, response, nativescript

I have a started a Nativescript app and I am trying to connect to my nodejs backend with an http post request but my response is undefined + my subscribe() function is unreachable when I call the service that is making the request.

Here the console.log returns the proper authKey.

```
app.post('/login', (request, response) => {
        const user = request.body;
        return data.login(user)
            .then((authKey) => {
                console.log(authKey)
                return response.json(authKey);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return response.json(err);
            });
    });
```

And the login func:

```
const login = (user) => {
        return db
            .collection('some collection')
            .findOne({ username: user.username })
            .then((foundUser) => {
                if (foundUser) {
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(user.password, foundUser.password)) {
                        return Promise.resolve(foundUser.authKey);
                    }
                    else {
                        throw Error('Wrong input');
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

This is my service, where I tried a couple of things like using map() to parse the response to json but the response itself here is undefined.

```
login(user) {
        return this.http.post('http://myip:3000/login', user);
    }
```

And how I use it. Here the console.log doenst even go off:

```
login() {
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }
    return this.authService.login(user)
      .subscribe((authKey) => {
        console.log(authKey);
      });
  }
```